# .find css class in a jQuery variable for further manipulation

Tags: jquery

I have some html in a jQuery variable

```
var banner = $("<div class='banner-textarea'></div>");
```

hot can i search "banner" and find banner-textarea so i can amend the html.

```
var LIs=ul.find("div.banner-textarea");
```

Above is not working!

Many thanks

Comment: Please show some more code. Where does `ul` come from?

Comment: Welcome to SO, please don't forget to visit http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: +1 for the welcome.. Welcome c14kaa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can search within your `jQuery object`.

```
banner.find('.banner-textarea').ApplySomeFunctions();
```

Unfortunatly, you didn't show where `ul` comes into play. You would need

```
var ul = $('<ul/>').append(banner)
```

to create such an object structure. That in turn, **makes no sense** obviously.

Answer (score 1):

This is asimple, you dont need to use append or find just add the context as the 2nd param like so

```
var banner = $("<div class='banner-textarea'></div>");

var texta = $("div.banner-textarea",banner);
```

this will tell jQuery to search only within the walls of banner and not the whole document.

Cant belive non of you guys know this :/

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1

Comment: This should definately be flagged as the answer.

Comment: Sorry not flagged as in reported for being offensive. The correct word probably should have been 'marked' as the answer

Comment: As a side note where can I find documentation about the second param overload?

Comment: Posted it in the OP, Theres not alot of documentation on this just shows one example of using root document[0] but as you can see in the version history in 1.0 it shows you *jQuery( selector, [ context ] )* and *contextA DOM Element, Document, or jQuery to use as context*

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you would like to do this, if it doesn't exist in the html, why would you like to find it?

I think you are looking for append function : [jQuery append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/)

```
$("#div_you_want_to_append_banner_in").append(banner);
```

Answer (score -2):

I think you need to read the jquery docs.

```
$('#banner-textarea')
```

will find the element in question assuming that you have an element in the page with an id of banner-textarea.

Comment: $('.banner-textarea'), since its a class not id :P